# Android Adding more than one TextView to a TableRow Programmatically

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, tablerow

I have a LinearLayout inside a FrameLayout for tab purposes. And I'm trying to add TableRow's to the LinearLayout in the code.

```
LinearLayout testLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.testLayout);
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

This gets my LinearLayout and creates a TableRow to the specifications I want. I know this part is working.

```
TextView textOne = new TextView(this);
textOne.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textOne.setText("One");

TextView textTwo = new TextView(this);
textTwo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textTwo.setText("Two");
```

Here I make my two TextViews with no problem.

```
tableRow.addView(textOne);
tableRow.addView(textTwo);
testLayout.addView(tableRow, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Here is where I assume everything goes wrong. What happens is it only shows the textTwo. I don't know why it's not showing both of them in order like a normal TableRow would in XML. And I repeat, this must be done in code.
Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported this `import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams`

Below code works for me

```
  TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.spreadsheet);
  TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
  LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  tr.setLayoutParams(lp);

  TextView tvLeft = new TextView(this);
  tvLeft.setLayoutParams(lp);
  tvLeft.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  tvLeft.setText("OMG");
  TextView tvCenter = new TextView(this);
  tvCenter.setLayoutParams(lp);
  tvCenter.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  tvCenter.setText("It");
  TextView tvRight = new TextView(this);
  tvRight.setLayoutParams(lp);
  tvRight.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  tvRight.setText("WORKED!!!");

  tr.addView(tvLeft);
  tr.addView(tvCenter);
  tr.addView(tvRight);

  tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

  tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create your TextView dynamically and should're getting error "removeView () parent." Here is a good solution for that:

```
TableView tlSkills = (TableView) findViewById(R.id.myTableView);
if(listSkills.size() > 0) {
     TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());

     int i = 0;
     for (Skills s : listSkills) {
     TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
     textView.setText("" + s.getName());

     tableRow.addView(textView);

     if(i > 0) { 
          tlSkills.removeView(tableRow);//this is to avoid the error I mentioned above.
     }

     tlSkills.addView(tableRow);

     i++;
  }
}
```